# Probability Distribution Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am thinking about general probability distributions and am wondering if any distribution can be written as a sum over some standard distribution (like Gaussians).

As a couple examples, we know that any one-dimensional function can be written as an infinite series of sines and cosines through Fourier expansion, and any two-dimensional function on a sphere can be written as an infinite sum of spherical harmonics.

The question is then if any probability distribution can be written as an infinite sum of Gaussian distributions, for example. If so, how would this look like mathematically?

Comment: You can use Kernel Density Estimation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation You can also use Gram-Charlier expansions and Edgeworth Series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series The first suggestion is closer to your question, the second is useful as it provides a way to expand a distribution in terms of its higher order moments (some considerations need be made to ensure non-negativity, which may require an expansion beyond skewness or kurtosis). My previous comment was deleted, just trying to help point you in the right direction.